# changing ttkboostrap button style

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkbootstrap

Could someone please help, i cannot set the style of a button after the button has already been created.

i asked the all knowing god of code, and `chatgpt` said that it is impossible, but i was hoping there might be another way to do it.

i tried using:

```
button.config('style' = 'light')
button['style'] == 'light'
```

i also tried changing the boarders and bg independently using the `.clam` thingy

i was expecting it to change but i just got many errors

Comment: Are you wanting to change the color of one button to something that is not in a style, or change the color of all buttons based on a style?

Comment: Use `.configure(bootstyle=...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

U can use button.config(style='primary.TButton') or button.configure(style='info.TButton'). Also button['style'] = 'primary.TButton' just chane 'primary.TButton' to your. Its all works with "bootstyle" atribute 2